# Accessing shared memory without synchronization can halts process or thread?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, shared-memory, scheduler

Summary: There is a reader thread and a writer thread accessing same memory space without synchronization. Is there any run-time error( NOT logical error ) or a risk of breaking the process or threads?

I'm trying to make a simple task scheduler.

There are some worker threads and they have their own task queue.

The task scheduler push tasks to the workers' queue.

I want the scheduler know the least busy thread, whose queue is shortest.

So I need some shared integer variables to store each queue's length.

Each worker thread writes the length of its own queue on specific variable.

And the scheduler reads that variables to know the shortest one.

So each variable has one read and one writer.

This is R-W problem and i need a mutex.

But i don't want any overhead and know the exact length of queues.

So I want to let the threads access the shared values without synchronization.

Is there any problem, without the inaccurate value?

Comment: I'm not aware of a potential problem on any "standard" MP architecture.  Depending on the architecture and your algorithm you may fetch invalid values, but they always should be values that were valid at some point in the past.

Comment: There's no way to answer this question as asked. It's not *about* anything in specific. Are you asking about a specific platform? Are you asking about a specific library? Are you asking about a specific standard? Who or what said it's a logical error to access the same memory space without synchronization? The specification for a language? If so, which? For a threading model? If so, which?

Comment: Some guy may be upset about my pool question. I understand them, but I want them to know about my poor English and coding skills... I have much more difficulties to find similar questions or write what exactly I'm meaning than native speakers. Yeah, there are many English users not native. But I'm not one of them.... furthermore, I'm a noob programmer! Anyway, now I know my mistakes and will effort not to do this again. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no law that says, for all platforms, all languages, and all standards what must happen when two threads access the same memory space without synchronization. Some platforms may allow it and add the synchronization themselves. That's not impossible. Some may test for it in all cases and guarantee that the process will crash. That's not impossible either.

As generic as this question is, the answer could be anything. You might as well ask "What happens if I do something I'm not supposed to do?"

POSIX, for example, allows the process to crash. Win32, for aligned 32-bit accesses, requires it to, at worst, give stale values. There's no universal law.

Comment: So you mean it's undefined, right? If so, It's a good answer for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not only is it undefined, it cannot be defined. There is no standard or entity with any kind of authority or ability to define such a thing for all languages, all platforms, all compilers and all threading libraries from now to eternity.